# Microsoft Azure Face API - Face Detection using Node-RED

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition, face-api

I'm creating a security application using face recognition so I need to recognize faces in real-time. And because I'm using Node-RED, I have chosen to use the Azure Face API.

[flow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm673.png)

In the first flow, I'm saving a new image got from the USB camera on my dropbox on the same filename. I mean the filename doesn't change. So every time, I trigger that flow, the image gets posted to dropbox with the same filename. In the next flow, I'm getting the face ID of that image. In the 3rd flow, I'm using Face Identify API to compare this image with the already trained models.

Let me explain the problem in 2 scenarios:

1) The USB camera captures an image of my face, it gets stored in dropbox and while triggering the 2nd flow, I'm able to get the face ID.

2) Again when I use the USB camera to capture an image, only this time, I'm not in front of the camera(camera captures an empty image), gets stored in dropbox, and while triggering the 2nd flow, even though it is an empty image, I get the same faceID I got before. And for successive captures, the same error follows.
The same happens if the camera detects an empty image first, for which it doesn't return any face ID and the 2nd time when I capture, even though the camera captures my face, the Face Detect API returns no face ID.

Is it because I'm saving the image in the same filename?? I'm doing so because I could use the same dropbox link (which I would have to get manually if I keep on generating new filenames) in the 2nd flow. 
I'm a newbie to Azure. Can someone help me through this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is with dropbox. The sharing links are pointing to the initial file and not the updated file. It is the same reason why node-red-node-dropbox dropbox in node doesn't work.

Comment: The problem was with the node-red-node-dropbox module. It has not been updated to the latest version.